# Thresholded AR(1) Forecast

Tags: time-series, forecasting, autoregressive

I want to find the forecast of an threshold AR(1) process:

[image: AR(1)]

I am confused on how to do it. Do I take the expected value of the process making $x_{t-1}$ become $x_n$, and $w_t$ becomes $w_{n+1}$, and then $w_{n+1}$ becomes 0, so we are left with $\theta_1 x_n$ for $x_n<0$?

What I want to show is that the forecast for that process is:

[image]

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a 
photograph or screenshot (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). 
When you retype the question, add the [tag:self-study] tag 
& read [its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've 
tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help 
you get unstuck.

Comment: Assuming $E[w_t=0],$ as is usual, another way to express your formula is $x^n_{n+1}=E[x_{n+1}\mid x_n].$